# How do I put a filename into a function?

Tags: python, regex

Here is probably a very stupid question coming from a rookie in python.
Is it possible to put a (text)file as the input in a function? If Yes, how to do it.

I am working with regular expressions and I try to use my function as a way  to select strings from a file, which in my case I called 'text'. The file name is called re_examples.txt. However instead they take the name of the file, instead of the content within in the file.

```
import re

def get_first_and_last_part (text):
    matcher2 = re.compile('([a-z]+)')
    match = matcher2.search(text)
    if match != None:
        first = match.start(1)
        last = match.end(1)
        before = text[:first-1]
        after = text[last+1:]
        return before, after
    else:
        return None, None # or some other value(s)
```

When I call the function with file name as the parameter I get this result.

```
get_first_and_last_part('re_examples.txt')
('re_examples.tx', 'examples.txt')
```

Comment: Yes, you can either: 1. `open` the file outside and pass in the resulting file handle; or 2. pass in the filename and `open` it inside the function. But Python won't see a string that looks like a file and think *"I know, they probably want that file opened"*, you need to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on if you want to modify the function itself, or if you want to leave it unchanged and simply change what you pass to it.

### Modify the function to accept a filename

If you want the argument to be a filename, just open the file and read it

```
def get_first_and_last_part (filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        text = f.read()
    matcher2 = re.compile('([a-z]+)')
    ...
```

### Leave the function unmodified

If you want to leave `get_first_and_last_part` unmodified, open the file before calling the function:

```
def get_first_and_last_part(text):
    ...
with open('re_examples.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
get_first_and_last_part(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your file first, using the 'open' method. So, you can open the file first and pass the contents of the file to your method. To do that what you can do is this

```
text = ""
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

# call method
get_first_and_last_part(text)
```